# how to hide part of HTML form depending on user role

Tags: php, html, kohana

I am developing a website using Kohana 3.3 and i want to selectively display HTML UI elements depending on the role of the user.
e:- If user is an admin then show the 'edit' hyperlink, and when the admin clicks the edit button change the textbox's from 'readonly' to 'normal'.

If user is an registered normal user than enable the button to 'ask a question'.

If user is a visitor then he have no priviliges.

Right now i am using a single view file and changing the visbility after checking the status of php variables. Somehow, i feel  that i am not doing it correctly, what is the suggested method to handle such scenarios( any plugins?) ?

Comment: It depends on how you save the user's information. e.g. for visitor save nothing in the cookie. For user generate a random number then hash it and put it into database to compare, so nobody can guess the hash. For administrator the same method, just use `$_COOKIE['hash_id']` and do some SQL Query and it will be alright.

Comment: Are you using the default Auth module (including roles)?

Comment: @kingkero yes ,I am using Auth and Roles

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want to distinguish three different cases

- visitor
- admin
- user

The place to handle this, is your controller. In this you have access to [`Auth::instance()->get_user()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/auth/login#logged-in-user).

```
$user = Auth::instance()->get_user();
if ($user === null) {
    //visitor
} else {
    if ($user->has('roles', ORM::factory('Role', array('name' => 'admin')))) {
        //admin
    } else {
        //user
    }
}
```

Now that you know how to handle the cases, you somehow need to tell your view. To do that, you can create a new variable in which you load either one of three views - one for each case.

```
$specificViewName = "";
$user = Auth::instance()->get_user();
if ($user === null) {
    $specificViewName = "visitor";
} else {
    if ($user->has('roles', ORM::factory('Role', array('name' => 'admin')))) {
        $specificViewName = "admin";
    } else {
        $specificViewName = "user";
    }
}
$specificView = View::factory("index/".$specificViewName);
```

If you are in a `Controller_Template`, you can now use `$this->template->set("specificView", $specificView);`.

In this case you'd have a *index* template like this

```
<html><!--etc.-->
<h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
<!--stuff all sites share like navigation-->
<?php print $specificView; ?>
<!--more-->
</html>
```

And *index/visitor*

```
<span class="sadtext">Nothing special for you here</span>
```

*index/user*

```
<form>
<button>ask a question!
</form>
```

*index/admin*

```
<a href="edit">hyperlink</a>
```

Comment: Thanks i will check your suggestion, but, in my case the UI elements are almost the same(except changing the readonly property if admin clicks 'edit' button and visibility of buttons, by having 3 different view i feel like i am replicating these files,

Comment: Well you can set a flag and react on that inside the view - however, that would not be clean MVC imo...