# kohana view change according to user logged or not

Tags: php, kohana

my question is trivial byt i am new and do not even know what to look for

i am using kohana framework to build my site. I have already learned how to use auth module (more or less) and created login, logout "arhitecture".

When my user is not logged i redirect to login page and when it is I use a view to show user data.

Now i am trying to do something like a page menu when i can see "login" button when user is not logged in, but "logout" button when logged. Do i make myself clear? I assume i cant redirect anywhere as this is a part of the same view. then how do I deterin a view content accordingly to a user state?

I am not looking for a ready code (although that would me apreciated) but a direction on what to look for and what to read about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to hide part of HTML form depending on user role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323414/how-to-hide-part-of-html-form-depending-on-user-role)

Answer (score 0):

For Kohana 3.2 you could check if a user is logged in by calling

```
Auth::instance()->logged_in();
```

An option of integration might be to build a base controller where the user is redirected or set in the before action. That way you always have the redirect in 1 place and the user set if there is a valid login.

```
class Controller_Custom extends Controller {

    protected $user;

    public function before()
    {
        if ( ! Auth::instance()->logged_in()) {
            $this->request->redirect('url/login/page');
        }

        $this->user = Auth::instance()->get_user();
    }
}
```

For Kohana 3.3 the redirect request is changed a bit I believe.

Comment: This is what OP already has - the question is, if he can differentiate within one view between logged in or not

Comment: You'll need some if else statements in the view, since you have your user object, you can easily check if the user is logged in in the view. Or include seperate templates.